# How to upload data (as a reactive object for processing in multiple places) and download data in the same App?

Tags: r, shiny, upload, shiny-reactivity

**See final working MWE code at the very bottom, incorporating suggestions made by gss!**

In running the below MWE code, if the user clicks the "Browse" button at the top of the sidebar panel and accesses a csv file, the data from that file is uploaded and presented as a table in the main panel. However, I would also like that csv data, as a matrix or vector, to be reflected in the matrix rendered in that sidebar panel. As shown in the image at the bottom. Any ideas for how to do this?

Below in MWE code you can see my commented-out `observeEvent()` triggered by "Browse" where I try doing this, including the use of the `updateMatrixInput()` function of the shinyMatrix package. It doesn't work.

Eventually I plan on eliminating the table rendering, as there is no point in seeing the same data twice. But for now for testing I'm trying to run them in parallel.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Optionally choose input file (csv)", accept = ".csv"),
      matrixInput("matrix1", 
                  value = matrix(c(5), ncol = 1, dimnames = list("Matrix 1 input",NULL)),
                  cols =  list(names = FALSE),
                  class = "numeric"),
      downloadButton("download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$file1,{
  #   tmpMat <- matrix(c(data), ncol=1)
  #   updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat)
  # })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Inputs","csv",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(input$matrix1[1,1], file,row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Final working MWE code based on gss solution:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Optionally choose input file (csv)", accept = ".csv"),
      matrixInput("matrix1", 
                  value = matrix(c(5), 
                          ncol = 1, 
                          dimnames = list("Matrix 1 input",NULL)
                  ),
                  cols =  list(names = FALSE),
                  class = "numeric"
      ),
      downloadButton("download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  input_file <- reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    input_file()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    updateMatrixInput(session, 
                      inputId = "matrix1", 
                      value = matrix(as.matrix(input_file()),
                                     ncol=1,
                                     dimnames = list("Matrix 1 input",NULL)
                              )
    )
                      
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Inputs","csv",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(input$matrix1[1,1], file,row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
```

What you need is to have an reactive, which later can be use in different places, so just:

```
input_file <- reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
})

output$contents <- renderTable({
    input_file()
  })
```

And you can use `input_file()` in other places now as well.

Comment: Hi gss! That works! However when I include the changed observeEvent() shown in the  edited post (at the top), when running the App and uploading a csv file the updated matrix is returned with brackets around the number ([5000] for example) . Any idea why it's bracketed and how to remove the brackets? I've never seen this before. Probably some error on my part in not subsetting the csv upload.

Comment: I don't know, "why", but I have found how to change this - use `tmpMat <- as.matrix(input_file(), ncol = 1)` or `tmpMat <- as.matrix(input_file())`, i.e. do not use `matrix`, but `as.matrix` and do not use `c()`. You can also try another combinations, but I see that these two mentioned do not display brackets.